# What sort my data in this graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, typescript

I am about to go crazy. My data looks like this and in the following order :

```
[
{
    "x": 0,
    "y": 200,
    "WeekNumber": 10
},
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": 300,
    "WeekNumber": 11
},
{
    "x": 2,
    "y": 400,
    "WeekNumber": 12
},
{
    "x": 3,
    "y": 200,
    "WeekNumber": 10
}
```

]

Where x is identifier for an object in the array, and weeknumber can go from 1-54, which means i can have 3 weeknumber 10 if i take span over 3 years. What i expect on my x axis is weeknumbers in following order : 10, 11, 12, 10. But for some reason something in d3js are sorting my data and result is 10, 10, 11, 12.

What does actually sort my data? and how do i solve this?

```
 public DrawGenericGraph(dataItems: Interfaces.IAreaChartItemList, parentId: string, id: string) {
    var data = dataItems.Models;
    var Xmax = d3.max(data, function (d: any) {
        return d.x;
    })

    this.shared.EmptyElement(id);

    var yMax = d3.max(data, function (d: any) {
        return d.y;
    })
    var width: number = this.shared.getParentWidth(parentId) - this.margin.Right - this.margin.Left;

    this.params = new GraphsHelper.GraphParameters(this.margin, this.height, width);

    var ticksCount = function () {
        if (data.length == 2) {
            return 1;
        }
        else
            return data.length;
    };

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([this.params.height, 0]);
    x.domain([0, Xmax]);
    y.domain([0, yMax]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function (d) {
            return dataItems.Format(d);
        }).ticks(ticksCount());

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.x); })
        .y0(this.params.height)
        .y1(function (d: any) { return y(d.y); });

    var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d: any) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function (d: any) { return y(d.y); });

    var svg = d3.select("#" + id).append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.params.OuterWidth)
        .attr("height", this.params.OuterHeight)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.params.Margin.Left + "," + this.params.Margin.Top + ")");

    y.nice()

    y.ticks().forEach(function (element) {
        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", function () { return 0; })
            .attr("y1", function () { return y(element); })
            .attr("x2", function () { return x(Xmax); })
            .attr("y2", function () { return y(element); })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
    })

    svg.append("g").append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.params.height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "yaxis")
        .call(yAxis);
});
```

Comment: Just attach an id field to the JSON objects (before or after loading) and use that to manually sort the array by id.

Comment: The data string you've posted here is not JSON.

Comment: Can  you make a Fiddle showing what you want to do?